# python: Mac OS X. malloc error. pointer being freed was not allocated. abort trap 6

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am running a multithreading python script. what it does is it will crawl the web and insert/update into mysql. here is my code

mythread.py

```
import threading
import time

class MyThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, threadname, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.threadname = threadname
        self.queue = q
        self.__exitFlag = False
        self.__signal_lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.threadname
        self.process_data()
        print "Exiting " + self.threadname

    def stop(self):
        with self.__signal_lock:
            self.__exitFlag = True

    def process_data(self):
        while not self.__exitFlag:
            if not self.queue.empty():
                data = self.queue.get()
                # crawl data from the web...
                # update to mysql
                # assuming we have already connected mysql:
                # db = MySQLDb()
                # db.connect
                query = ""
                db.query(query)
```

mysql_db.py

```
class MySQLDb:
    conn = None

    def connect(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            host="127.0.0.1",
            user = "root",
            passwd = "password",
            db = "moviestats")

        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    def query(self, sql):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            self.conn.commit()
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
            # solution to: MySQL server has gone away
            self.cursor.close()
            self.connect()
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            self.conn.commit()
```

Here is the error log:

```
Process:         Python [905]
Path:            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.7 (2.7.7)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [751]
Responsible:     Terminal [410]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-07-09 22:31:43.221 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Report Version:  11
....

....
Crashed Thread:  5

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x100a4b600: pointer being freed was not allocated
......
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83153866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8de8735c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8ef88b1a abort + 125
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff8220707f free + 411
4   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x0000000101027302 vio_delete + 44
5   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x000000010100709a end_server + 48
6   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x0000000101006f81 cli_safe_read + 49
7   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x000000010100b469 cli_read_query_result + 26
8   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x000000010100a648 mysql_real_query + 83
9   _mysql.so                       0x0000000100533be8 _mysql_ConnectionObject_query + 85
10  org.python.python               0x00000001000c2fad PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21405
11  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3bfa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24554
12  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3bfa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24554
13  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4fb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
14  org.python.python               0x00000001000c33f0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22496
15  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3bfa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24554
16  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3bfa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24554
17  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4fb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
18  org.python.python               0x00000001000c33f0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22496
19  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3bfa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24554
20  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3bfa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24554
21  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3bfa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24554
22  org.python.python               0x00000001000c4fb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
23  org.python.python               0x000000010003eac0 function_call + 176
24  org.python.python               0x000000010000ceb2 PyObject_Call + 98
25  org.python.python               0x000000010001f56d instancemethod_call + 365
26  org.python.python               0x000000010000ceb2 PyObject_Call + 98
27  org.python.python               0x00000001000bc957 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87
28  org.python.python               0x0000000100102f27 t_bootstrap + 71
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8de86899 _pthread_body + 138
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8de8672a _pthread_start + 137
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8de8afc9 thread_start + 13
```

I ran the script with 50 threads. The error occur is intermittent but it's repeatable. I narrow down the problem and it's due to the insertion/update to mysql. I read that it could be due to concurrency issue, but how do i fix it?

Comment: Python code is not supposed to dump core. If you're getting a crash like that, it's a bug in the MySQL binding. Once you find the cause, you should file a bug with the MySQL-python people.

Comment: tks for the quick reply. i shall debug further on mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran in to the same malloc error on OSX using MySQLdb. The thing that was causing my error was that was sharing MySQLdb connections between threads. Using a connection per thread fixed it for me.

From the documentation http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html:

> The MySQL protocol can not handle multiple threads using the same
>   connection at once. Some earlier versions of MySQLdb utilized locking
>   to achieve a threadsafety of 2. While this is not terribly hard to
>   accomplish using the standard Cursor class (which uses
>   mysql_store_result()), it is complicated by SSCursor (which uses
>   mysql_use_result(); with the latter you must ensure all the rows have
>   been read before another query can be executed. It is further
>   complicated by the addition of transactions, since transactions start
>   when a cursor execute a query, but end when COMMIT or ROLLBACK is
>   executed by the Connection object. Two threads simply cannot share a
>   connection while a transaction is in progress, in addition to not
>   being able to share it during query execution. This excessively
>   complicated the code to the point where it just isn't worth it.
>
> The general upshot of this is: Don't share connections between
>   threads. It's really not worth your effort or mine, and in the end,
>   will probably hurt performance, since the MySQL server runs a separate
>   thread for each connection. You can certainly do things like cache
>   connections in a pool, and give those connections to one thread at a
>   time. If you let two threads use a connection simultaneously, the
>   MySQL client library will probably upchuck and die. You have been
>   warned.

Comment: Yup you are right. A dedicated connection per thread works for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I thought about ways to not multi-thread access to the database.  And upon further thought I believe it is a bad practice to have lots of threads with connections (or at least it can be tricky business).  Think about ways to do bulk reads and writes and do the multi-threading on the processing without the database being involved.

This may still be a bug in the Python binding, but I was able to make progress by simplifying  how the program was accessing the database and parallelizing the code where it really needed to be parallelized.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi i agree with you. In fact i decided to do just that yesterday. Now i am using  sqlalchemy which adds the query buy not commit until all threads have finished their task. It works!!!

Comment: Cool idea! I was just accumulating rows to insert to a list and then bulk inserting them, but I like your idea better :)

Answer (score 1):

In general this error may be stochastic. I ran into this error, but after running the program again did not receive the error. I ran my program (which is unrelated to mysql_db although also complex) 5 times. I only found this error on the first and fourth run.